# Could not find valid 'id' or 'value' in the Parent Option object

Tags: json, jira

I tried various ways to resolve the issue but unable to figure out what's wrong with the JSON, looking for some help on this.

```
{
  "fields": {
    "project": {
      "key": "DCIPTQA"
    },
    "customfield_17304": [
      {
        "set": {
          "value": "[entry.systemsIntegrationComplexity.label]"
        }
      }
    ],
    "customfield_13750": [
      {
        "set": {
          "value": "[entry.f1.Type1.label]"
        }
      }
    ],
    "customfield_17305": [
      {
        "set": {
          "value": "[entry.externalSystems.label]"
        }
      }
    ],
    "issuetype": {
      "name": "Program Intake"
    }
  }
}
```

**Error** : Seeing could not find valid 'id' or 'value' in the Parent Option object

```
{
  "errorMessages": [],
  "errors": {
    "customfield_17304": "Could not find valid 'id' or 'value' in the Parent Option object.",
    "customfield_13750": "Could not find valid 'id' or 'value' in the Parent Option object.",
    "customfield_17305": "Could not find valid 'id' or 'value' in the Parent Option object."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve by making below changes to json body

```
{
  "fields": {
    "project": {
      "key": "DCIPTQA"
    },
    "customfield_17304": {
      "value": "[entry.systemsIntegrationComplexity.id]"
    },
    "customfield_13750": {
      "value": "[entry.f1.Type1.id]"
    },
    "customfield_17305": {
      "value": "[entry.externalSystems.id]"
    },
    "issuetype": {
      "name": "Program Intake"
    }
  }
}
```